# VB.NET SetFocus Equivalent for Enter Button?

Tags: vb.net, focus, enter, setfocus

I have a textbox called clientFirst and, if I press Enter after I'm done typing in this textbox, I want the Enter button to represent a click on btnAdd. How can I make this happen?

```
Protected Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As ImageClickEventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
    'Do something       
End Sub
```

There's not much code to post, really. :( But I was suggested to use the KeyDown function by Chase Ernst, which seems like a brilliant idea, except that it keeps telling me that a part of it is undefined. Here's the code I was suggested:

```
Private Sub clientFirst_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles clientFirst.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        btnAdd.PerformClick()
    End If
End Sub
```

It keeps telling me that `System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs` is undefined. I'm guessing there's an `Imports` class I have to define at the top? Tried `System.Windows`, `System.Object`, `System.Windows.Forms`, `System.KeyEventArgs` and nothing works!

Thank you in advance! x

Comment: ASP.NET or Windows Forms?

Comment: ASP.NET, please. Building a website, already hosting online. :)

Comment: So `Button1.PerformClick()` and all of the `System` methods arent working?

Comment: @ChaseErnst Yup. `PerformClick is not a member of 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button'`, and `Type 'System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs' is not defined.`

Comment: I beleive this is because it is a web application, I am just researching the correct way to go around this.

Comment: @ChaseErnst You're my hero.

Comment: @ChaseErnst No news? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy way is to use the [HTMLForm.DefaltButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlform.defaultbutton.aspx) property on the form.

```
 Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
     Page.Form.DefaultButton = "TextBox1"
 End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, really :) But that's not what I meant. I meant I needed the site to detect an Enter key and react to it.

Comment: Ignore my previous comment, @Ceres! Works perfectly, I mis-read the code and misunderstood it myself!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like this:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        Button1.PerformClick()
    End If
End Sub
```

If the key that is pressed is the enter key, then `Button1.PerformClick()` will fire.

Comment: Thanks a billion! :) I'll try it out now and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Okay, if it works, please take some time to upvote and make as correct answer.

Comment: Ignore the pre-edit material, I can't seem to call the Button1 sub-routine, which is already defined as Button1_Click with two parameters.

Comment: Can you post the code? and I believe that when you press enter. The `Button1.PerformClick()` will initiate the sub routine for your button.

Comment: Yeah sure, I'll post the code but it's a bit messy. One minute, I'll edit the main post.

Comment: Done! Check the main post :)